# Is there a way to insert a character into a RegExp pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am refactoring a series of RegExp a/b patterns that are used in two ways.

One uses the `^` as the third character.

`/[^a-zA-Z0-9,?@&!#'"~ _;\.\*\/\-\+ ]/`

The other doesn't use the `^`

`/[a-zA-Z0-9,?@&!#'"~ _;\.\*\/\-\+ ]/`

Rather than write this pattern in two way is there a way to write it once and add the `^` to a second version?

This throws an error but as an example is there something available like this?

`varOne = /[a-zA-Z0-9,?@&!#'"~ _;\.\*\/\-\+ ]/`

`varTwo = [varOne.slice(0, 1), '^', varOne.slice(1)].join('')`

Comment: What are you *trying* to do? Do you understand what the `^` means in this context (it’s a special character)? If you want help, please provide an explanation of what you want to do, what you’ve tried, and what’s wrong with your efforts. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Ed Cottrell I'm attempting to add a character into a RegExp pattern.  Very useful if possible.

Comment: Also, that last line is almost certainly not something you want.

Comment: Okay, but *what does that mean*? What are you trying to add, where, and for what purpose? Hint: you can’t just insert `^` anywhere you want in a regex. What are you trying? What’s the problem you’re really trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to generate a regex from string:

```js
const regex = caret => `[${caret ? '^' : ''}a-zA-Z0-9,?@&!#'"~ _;\\.\\*\\/\\-\\+ ]`

const regex1 = new RegExp(regex(true));
const regex2 = new RegExp(regex(false));

console.log(regex1.test('%'));
console.log(regex1.test('abc'));

console.log(regex2.test('abc'));
console.log(regex2.test('%'));
```

Comment: I knew the RegExp constructor existed but I never used it before because I couldn't see the practical need for it.  Now I understand why we've got that option.